# Add Custom Image library to Microsoft Office

Tags: microsoft-office, images, sharepoint-2010

Does Microsoft Office support the ability to use a custom image library so that we can ensure images are 'on brand'?

We have an internal image library in SharePoint which should be used for all presentations, documents etc in our organisation. We've tried opening the SharePoint site from the insert image dialog but wondered if there was a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Use Microsoft Office template.